# Finding 36 integer solutions to a set of 14 equations using various boundary conditions

Tags: equation-solving, random, filtering, integer-sequence, code

What is good way to solve this system of equations? I have it run now for quite some time and it does not spit out a solution.

```
n = 857097;
Solve[{n == n1^3 + n2^3 + n3^3 + n4^3 + n5^3 + n6^3, 
  n == n7^3 + n8^3 + n9^3 + n10^3 + n11^3 + n12^3, 
  n == n13^3 + n14^3 + n15^3 + n16^3 + n17^3 + n18^3, 
  n == n19^3 + n20^3 + n21^3 + n22^3 + n23^3 + n24^3, 
  n == n25^3 + n26^3 + n27^3 + n28^3 + n29^3 + n30^3, 
  n == n31^3 + n32^3 + n33^3 + n34^3 + n35^3 + n36^3, 
  n == n1^3 + n7^3 + n13^3 + n19^3 + n25^3 + n31^3, 
  n == n2^3 + n8^3 + n14^3 + n20^3 + n26^3 + n32^3, 
  n == n3^3 + n9^3 + n15^3 + n21^3 + n27^3 + n33^3, 
  n == n4^3 + n10^3 + n16^3 + n22^3 + n28^3 + n34^3, 
  n == n5^3 + n11^3 + n17^3 + n23^3 + n29^3 + n35^3, 
  n == n6^3 + n12^3 + n18^3 + n24^3 + n30^3 + n36^3, 
  n == n1^3 + n8^3 + n15^3 + n22^3 + n29^3 + n36^3, 
  n == n6^3 + n11^3 + n16^3 + n21^3 + n26^3 + n31^3, 
  1 <= n1 < 100 && 1 <= n2 < 100 && 1 <= n3 < 100 && 1 <= n4 < 100 && 
   1 <= n5 < 100 && 1 <= n6 < 100 && 1 <= n7 < 100 && 1 <= n8 < 100 &&
    1 <= n9 < 100 && 1 <= n10 < 100 && 1 <= n11 < 100 && 
   1 <= n12 < 100 && 1 <= n13 < 100 && 1 <= n14 < 100 && 
   1 <= n15 < 100 && 1 <= n16 < 100 && 1 <= n17 < 100 && 
   1 <= n18 < 100 && 1 <= n19 < 100 && 1 <= n20 < 100 && 
   1 <= n21 < 100 && 1 <= n22 < 100 && 1 <= n23 < 100 && 
   1 <= n24 < 100 && 1 <= n25 < 100 && 1 <= n26 < 100 && 
   1 <= n27 < 100 && 1 <= n28 < 100 && 1 <= n29 < 100 && 
   1 <= n30 < 100 && 1 <= n31 < 100 && 1 <= n32 < 100 && 
   1 <= n33 < 100 && 1 <= n34 < 100 && 1 <= n35 < 100 && 
   1 <= n36 < 100}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, 
  n12, n13, n14, n15, n16, n17, n18, n19, n20, n21, n22, n23, n24, 
  n25, n26, n27, n28, n29, n30, n31, n32, n33, n34, n35, 
  n36}, Integers]
```

**EDIT:**

The problem I keep running into is that I have to find a unique solution, such that none of the variables is equal to each other.

[image]

Comment: It might be worth finding all possible solutions to the first equation, and consider permutations of these.

Comment: @mikado Thank you for your comment. Is there a way to program that in a smart way, such that Mathematica can solve for the rest of the equations after solving that problem first.

Comment: This is rather a math question than Mathematica question.

Comment: @user64494 I want to use Mathematica to solve it.

Comment: The following `n = 857097;FindInstance[n == n1^3 + n2^3 + n3^3 + n4^3 + n5^3 + n6^3 && 1 <= n1 < 100 && 
 1 <= n2 < 100 && 1 <= n3 < 100 && 1 <= n4 < 100 && 1 <= n5 < 100 && 
  1 <= n6 < 100, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6}, Integers]` works. The result is `(* {{n1 -> 1, n2 -> 1, n3 -> 29, n4 -> 45, n5 -> 53, n6 -> 84}}*) `.

Comment: Are you confident that a solution exists?

Comment: @bbgodfrey No I am not, but I have other values of $n$ to try, so when I have a working code I can try other values of $n$.

Comment: I do not believe that the code in your question, even if modified to produce only distinct values of `n`, will produce results within weeks of computing.  Almost certainly, the computation you tried quickly used up your computer's memory and then slowed down enormously.  However, even with infinite memory, the computation would be very slow.  The method described by @kgir in his now deleted answer is the most promising option I have found, but even it would take an enormous amount of time to test the billions of possibilities he found against all 14 equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I've recognized that your equations actually represent a kind of magic square of cubes, which wasn't mentioned in the question or comments. I've coded how to generate the equations and constraints without writing them all out 'manually' - hopefully this is useful if you explore similar, smaller, more tractable problems.

Your problem is very hard, and I don't expect this will ever finish and return 36 results, but this is how you'd solve it if you had all the time and memory in the world:

```
c = 857097;
variables = Array[x, 36];
matrix = ArrayReshape[variables, {6, 6}];

magicSquareConstraint = And @@ Flatten[{
  (* rows of the matrix *)
    c == # & /@ Total[Transpose[matrix^3]],
  (* columns of the matrix *)
    c == # & /@ Total[matrix^3],
  (* Both diagonals of the matrix *)
    c == Total[Diagonal[matrix^3]],
    c == Total[Diagonal[Reverse[matrix^3, 2]]]
}];

uniqueConstraint = (And @@ (Unequal @@@ Subsets[variables, {2}]));
rangeConstraint = (And @@ (1 <= # < 100 & /@ variables));

FindInstance[
 magicSquareConstraint  && uniqueConstraint && rangeConstraint,
 variables, PositiveIntegers, 36
]
```

Another possibility is to find random 6x6 magic squares for the linear problem over domain $1\le x_i<100$ using `LinearOptimization`. This is much faster than `FindInstance` and see [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223940/72682). Then you could cube the solutions to the linear problem and check the constraints are still valid. However, I suspect upon cubing, most magic squares would not preserve the magic property.

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide you 99 number combinations that all fit the conditions. Pick the right one out to get your magic cube.

The cubic of the first 94 numbers is below n. Combine them all with a boole number r[i] and use NMinimize and NMaximize to find allowed combinations. (This takes about 20 minutes). Retransform the r[i] to i and delete multiples with Union.

```
n = 857097;
rn = Array[r, 94];
rr = Range[94]^3;
tot = Total@rn == 6;
int = rn \[Element] Integers;
th01 = And @@ Thread[0 <= rn <= 1];

(tabmin = 
  Table[DeleteCases[
 rn (rn /. 
    NMinimize[{r[j], tot && int && th01 && rn.rr == n}, rn][[2]]),
  0], {j, 1, 94}]) // Timing
```

Do the same with tabmax  ... NMaximize...

```
ncomb = Join[tabmin, tabmax] /. r[aa_] -> aa // Union;
```

I leave it to you to find fitting combinations.

```
ncomb = {{1, 2, 3, 21, 72, 78}, {1, 2, 4, 58, 59, 77}, {1, 2, 6, 16, 
42, 92}, {1, 2, 8, 12, 64, 84}, {1, 2, 9, 14, 58, 87}, {1, 2, 12, 
36, 60, 84}, {1, 2, 32, 46, 56, 82}, {1, 3, 14, 15, 71, 79}, {1, 
5, 34, 54, 62, 75}, {1, 6, 9, 15, 42, 92}, {1, 8, 18, 42, 52, 
86}, {1, 8, 22, 35, 69, 78}, {1, 9, 21, 39, 60, 83}, {1, 10, 20, 
34, 47, 89}, {1, 13, 20, 48, 68, 75}, {1, 22, 47, 50, 65, 70}, {2,
 3, 7, 37, 65, 81}, {2, 4, 17, 35, 58, 85}, {2, 4, 24, 28, 57, 
86}, {2, 7, 10, 29, 30, 93}, {2, 8, 9, 10, 64, 84}, {2, 8, 16, 18,
 49, 90}, {2, 11, 19, 51, 70, 72}, {2, 18, 28, 30, 46, 89}, {2, 
32, 34, 49, 64, 74}, {3, 5, 27, 31, 68, 79}, {3, 6, 13, 54, 57, 
80}, {3, 7, 14, 38, 52, 87}, {3, 13, 15, 33, 48, 89}, {4, 5, 9, 
11, 64, 84}, {4, 5, 12, 17, 27, 94}, {4, 5, 45, 47, 48, 82}, {4, 
6, 17, 33, 54, 87}, {4, 6, 39, 49, 65, 74}, {4, 6, 41, 48, 62, 
76}, {4, 7, 29, 32, 70, 77}, {4, 7, 38, 44, 57, 81}, {4, 9, 11, 
13, 42, 92}, {4, 9, 14, 39, 73, 74}, {4, 9, 18, 43, 68, 77}, {4, 
9, 38, 44, 70, 72}, {4, 10, 32, 42, 65, 78}, {4, 12, 14, 57, 64, 
74}, {4, 15, 20, 32, 39, 91}, {4, 17, 22, 32, 60, 84}, {4, 17, 29,
 43, 70, 74}, {4, 18, 48, 51, 63, 71}, {4, 20, 25, 44, 70, 
74}, {4, 21, 30, 35, 57, 84}, {4, 24, 33, 47, 68, 73}, {4, 28, 32,
 41, 46, 86}, {4, 30, 40, 56, 57, 74}, {4, 30, 42, 53, 57, 
75}, {4, 31, 38, 41, 68, 73}, {5, 7, 19, 21, 69, 80}, {5, 10, 20, 
24, 31, 93}, {5, 13, 20, 34, 68, 79}, {5, 23, 33, 45, 55, 82}, {5,
 28, 38, 45, 63, 76}, {6, 7, 17, 31, 63, 83}, {6, 7, 23, 25, 29, 
93}, {6, 8, 25, 42, 44, 88}, {6, 8, 31, 55, 62, 75}, {6, 9, 18, 
32, 70, 78}, {6, 9, 21, 32, 51, 88}, {6, 10, 15, 27, 47, 90}, {6, 
11, 30, 37, 57, 84}, {6, 12, 14, 19, 73, 77}, {6, 12, 17, 18, 24, 
94}, {6, 12, 19, 20, 33, 93}, {6, 14, 25, 29, 51, 88}, {6, 16, 17,
 45, 59, 82}, {6, 23, 35, 36, 64, 79}, {6, 26, 27, 37, 40, 
89}, {6, 28, 47, 56, 61, 69}, {6, 38, 45, 55, 60, 69}, {7, 8, 12, 
29, 60, 85}, {7, 8, 16, 27, 71, 78}, {7, 8, 22, 25, 50, 89}, {7, 
9, 22, 53, 65, 75}, {7, 9, 50, 52, 57, 74}, {7, 11, 15, 29, 42, 
91}, {7, 25, 44, 53, 57, 75}, {7, 26, 41, 49, 52, 80}, {7, 29, 30,
 32, 45, 88}, {7, 32, 51, 57, 59, 67}, {8, 9, 15, 18, 49, 90}, {8,
 13, 27, 33, 61, 83}, {8, 20, 27, 31, 52, 87}, {8, 21, 43, 49, 56,
 78}, {8, 28, 30, 37, 57, 83}, {8, 29, 31, 39, 63, 79}, {8, 33, 
34, 38, 66, 76}, {8, 35, 43, 58, 62, 67}, {9, 11, 29, 46, 52, 
84}, {9, 26, 42, 46, 64, 74}, {10, 28, 33, 48, 56, 80}, {11, 18, 
20, 25, 28, 93}, {12, 14, 18, 25, 58, 86}
};
```

Test

```
Total@(#^3) & /@ ncomb
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run your code.

Comment: Without knowing what error, i can't say anything. On my pc it works. Remember tabmax with NMaximize is not shown.

Comment: I edited a picture in my question above, where the error is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, i corrected it tabmin[[2]] was wrong. Simpliy tabmin.

Comment: Okay thanks! But I do not know how to filter the solutions with this number of solutions, can you help me a bit further?

Comment: Were you able to get at least one solution out of this? I am equally interested in solving these magic square type problems.