# How to program a situation like the following in mathematics and generalize the process to other configurations?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, programming, string-manipulation

Distribute the numbers from 1 to 10(view image) so that the sum of each row and each column is the same and
a) the maximum possible
b) the minimum possible
(I put it from 1 to 10 for ease)

I know it is a problem that could work with matrices or lists but I can't think how to start

[image]

*Edition:
Clarification of the sums that must be equal*

[image]

Comment: Five rows/columns might work better than four.

Comment: Related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223940/72682

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Index the cells:

```
1 * * 2
3 4 5 6
7 * * 8
9 * * 10
```

Define a $10\times 10$ zero-one matrix $M$, where $M_{i,j}=1$ iff number $i$ is in $j^\text{th}$ cell, and $0$ otherwise.

Constraints:

- Every number in unique cell: $\sum_j M_{I,j}=1 \quad \forall_I$
- Every cell has unique number: $\sum_i M_{i,J}=1 \quad \forall_J$
- $n_j=$ (Number in $j^\text{th}$ cell) $=\sum_i {(i M_{i,j})}$, hence $n_1+n_2=n_3+n_4+n_5+n_6=\dots$

Into *Mathematica* code:

```
cons1 = Table[Sum[m[i, j], {j, 10}] == 1, {i, 10}];

cons2 = Table[Sum[m[i, j], {i, 10}] == 1, {j, 10}];

n[j_] := Sum[i*m[i, j], {i, 10}]
cons3 = Equal @@ 
  Append[Plus @@@ 
    Map[n, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 3, 7, 
       9}, {4}, {5}, {2, 6, 8, 10}}, {-1}], k];

domCons = {k \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
  Table[{0 <= m[i, j] <= 1, m[i, j] \[Element] Integers}, {i, 10}, {j,
     10}]};

vars = Append[Flatten@Table[m[i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}], k];
```

Then optimize the sum `k` with the linear constraints:

```
LinearOptimization[k, {cons1, cons2, cons3, domCons}, vars]
```

We'll see this problem is unsolvable:

> **LinearOptimization::nsolc:** There are no points that satisfy the constraints.

Generalization is similar.

## Update

I misread the problem. In this case we only need to modify `cons3` so that $n_3+n_4+n_5+n_6=n_1+n_3+n_7+n_9=n_2+n_6+n_8+n_{10}$:

```
cons3 = Equal @@ 
   Append[Plus @@@ 
     Map[n, {{3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 7, 9}, {2, 6, 8, 10}}, {-1}], k];
```

### a) the maximum possible

Run `LinearOptimization[-k, ...]` to get maximum sum 24:

> ```
> {m[1, 1] -> 1, m[1, 2] -> 0, m[1, 3] -> 0, m[1, 4] -> 0, m[1, 5] -> 0,
>   m[1, 6] -> 0, m[1, 7] -> 0, m[1, 8] -> 0, m[1, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[1, 10] -> 0, m[2, 1] -> 0, m[2, 2] -> 0, m[2, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[2, 4] -> 1, m[2, 5] -> 0, m[2, 6] -> 0, m[2, 7] -> 0, m[2, 8] -> 0,
>   m[2, 9] -> 0, m[2, 10] -> 0, m[3, 1] -> 0, m[3, 2] -> 0, 
>  m[3, 3] -> 0, m[3, 4] -> 0, m[3, 5] -> 0, m[3, 6] -> 0, m[3, 7] -> 0,
>   m[3, 8] -> 0, m[3, 9] -> 0, m[3, 10] -> 1, m[4, 1] -> 0, 
>  m[4, 2] -> 0, m[4, 3] -> 0, m[4, 4] -> 0, m[4, 5] -> 0, m[4, 6] -> 0,
>   m[4, 7] -> 0, m[4, 8] -> 0, m[4, 9] -> 1, m[4, 10] -> 0, 
>  m[5, 1] -> 0, m[5, 2] -> 0, m[5, 3] -> 0, m[5, 4] -> 0, m[5, 5] -> 1,
>   m[5, 6] -> 0, m[5, 7] -> 0, m[5, 8] -> 0, m[5, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[5, 10] -> 0, m[6, 1] -> 0, m[6, 2] -> 1, m[6, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[6, 4] -> 0, m[6, 5] -> 0, m[6, 6] -> 0, m[6, 7] -> 0, m[6, 8] -> 0,
>   m[6, 9] -> 0, m[6, 10] -> 0, m[7, 1] -> 0, m[7, 2] -> 0, 
>  m[7, 3] -> 0, m[7, 4] -> 0, m[7, 5] -> 0, m[7, 6] -> 1, m[7, 7] -> 0,
>   m[7, 8] -> 0, m[7, 9] -> 0, m[7, 10] -> 0, m[8, 1] -> 0, 
>  m[8, 2] -> 0, m[8, 3] -> 0, m[8, 4] -> 0, m[8, 5] -> 0, m[8, 6] -> 0,
>   m[8, 7] -> 0, m[8, 8] -> 1, m[8, 9] -> 0, m[8, 10] -> 0, 
>  m[9, 1] -> 0, m[9, 2] -> 0, m[9, 3] -> 0, m[9, 4] -> 0, m[9, 5] -> 0,
>   m[9, 6] -> 0, m[9, 7] -> 1, m[9, 8] -> 0, m[9, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[9, 10] -> 0, m[10, 1] -> 0, m[10, 2] -> 0, m[10, 3] -> 1, 
>  m[10, 4] -> 0, m[10, 5] -> 0, m[10, 6] -> 0, m[10, 7] -> 0, 
>  m[10, 8] -> 0, m[10, 9] -> 0, m[10, 10] -> 0, k -> 24}
> ```

Visualization (see below):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & \_ & \_ & 6 \\
 10 & 2 & 5 & 7 \\
 9 & \_ & \_ & 8 \\
 4 & \_ & \_ & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

### b) the minimum possible

Run `LinearOptimization[k, ...]` to get minimum sum 20:

> ```
> {m[1, 1] -> 0, m[1, 2] -> 0, m[1, 3] -> 0, m[1, 4] -> 0, m[1, 5] -> 0,
>   m[1, 6] -> 1, m[1, 7] -> 0, m[1, 8] -> 0, m[1, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[1, 10] -> 0, m[2, 1] -> 0, m[2, 2] -> 0, m[2, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[2, 4] -> 0, m[2, 5] -> 0, m[2, 6] -> 0, m[2, 7] -> 1, m[2, 8] -> 0,
>   m[2, 9] -> 0, m[2, 10] -> 0, m[3, 1] -> 0, m[3, 2] -> 0, 
>  m[3, 3] -> 0, m[3, 4] -> 0, m[3, 5] -> 0, m[3, 6] -> 0, m[3, 7] -> 0,
>   m[3, 8] -> 0, m[3, 9] -> 0, m[3, 10] -> 1, m[4, 1] -> 0, 
>  m[4, 2] -> 0, m[4, 3] -> 1, m[4, 4] -> 0, m[4, 5] -> 0, m[4, 6] -> 0,
>   m[4, 7] -> 0, m[4, 8] -> 0, m[4, 9] -> 0, m[4, 10] -> 0, 
>  m[5, 1] -> 0, m[5, 2] -> 0, m[5, 3] -> 0, m[5, 4] -> 0, m[5, 5] -> 0,
>   m[5, 6] -> 0, m[5, 7] -> 0, m[5, 8] -> 0, m[5, 9] -> 1, 
>  m[5, 10] -> 0, m[6, 1] -> 0, m[6, 2] -> 1, m[6, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[6, 4] -> 0, m[6, 5] -> 0, m[6, 6] -> 0, m[6, 7] -> 0, m[6, 8] -> 0,
>   m[6, 9] -> 0, m[6, 10] -> 0, m[7, 1] -> 0, m[7, 2] -> 0, 
>  m[7, 3] -> 0, m[7, 4] -> 1, m[7, 5] -> 0, m[7, 6] -> 0, m[7, 7] -> 0,
>   m[7, 8] -> 0, m[7, 9] -> 0, m[7, 10] -> 0, m[8, 1] -> 0, 
>  m[8, 2] -> 0, m[8, 3] -> 0, m[8, 4] -> 0, m[8, 5] -> 1, m[8, 6] -> 0,
>   m[8, 7] -> 0, m[8, 8] -> 0, m[8, 9] -> 0, m[8, 10] -> 0, 
>  m[9, 1] -> 1, m[9, 2] -> 0, m[9, 3] -> 0, m[9, 4] -> 0, m[9, 5] -> 0,
>   m[9, 6] -> 0, m[9, 7] -> 0, m[9, 8] -> 0, m[9, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[9, 10] -> 0, m[10, 1] -> 0, m[10, 2] -> 0, m[10, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[10, 4] -> 0, m[10, 5] -> 0, m[10, 6] -> 0, m[10, 7] -> 0, 
>  m[10, 8] -> 1, m[10, 9] -> 0, m[10, 10] -> 0, k -> 20}
> ```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 9 & \_ & \_ & 6 \\
 4 & 7 & 8 & 1 \\
 2 & \_ & \_ & 10 \\
 5 & \_ & \_ & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

---

## Addendum

If we loosen the constraints so that only the sums of 1st row and 2nd row are equal:

```
cons3 = Equal @@ 
  Append[Plus @@@ Map[n, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}, {-1}], k];
```

This is a solvable case:

```
solution = LinearOptimization[k, {cons1, cons2, cons3, domCons}, vars]
```

> ```
> {m[1, 1] -> 0, m[1, 2] -> 0, m[1, 3] -> 0, m[1, 4] -> 0, m[1, 5] -> 0,
>   m[1, 6] -> 1, m[1, 7] -> 0, m[1, 8] -> 0, m[1, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[1, 10] -> 0, m[2, 1] -> 0, m[2, 2] -> 0, m[2, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[2, 4] -> 0, m[2, 5] -> 1, m[2, 6] -> 0, m[2, 7] -> 0, m[2, 8] -> 0,
>   m[2, 9] -> 0, m[2, 10] -> 0, m[3, 1] -> 0, m[3, 2] -> 0, 
>  m[3, 3] -> 0, m[3, 4] -> 1, m[3, 5] -> 0, m[3, 6] -> 0, m[3, 7] -> 0,
>   m[3, 8] -> 0, m[3, 9] -> 0, m[3, 10] -> 0, m[4, 1] -> 0, 
>  m[4, 2] -> 1, m[4, 3] -> 0, m[4, 4] -> 0, m[4, 5] -> 0, m[4, 6] -> 0,
>   m[4, 7] -> 0, m[4, 8] -> 0, m[4, 9] -> 0, m[4, 10] -> 0, 
>  m[5, 1] -> 0, m[5, 2] -> 0, m[5, 3] -> 1, m[5, 4] -> 0, m[5, 5] -> 0,
>   m[5, 6] -> 0, m[5, 7] -> 0, m[5, 8] -> 0, m[5, 9] -> 0, 
>  m[5, 10] -> 0, m[6, 1] -> 0, m[6, 2] -> 0, m[6, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[6, 4] -> 0, m[6, 5] -> 0, m[6, 6] -> 0, m[6, 7] -> 1, m[6, 8] -> 0,
>   m[6, 9] -> 0, m[6, 10] -> 0, m[7, 1] -> 1, m[7, 2] -> 0, 
>  m[7, 3] -> 0, m[7, 4] -> 0, m[7, 5] -> 0, m[7, 6] -> 0, m[7, 7] -> 0,
>   m[7, 8] -> 0, m[7, 9] -> 0, m[7, 10] -> 0, m[8, 1] -> 0, 
>  m[8, 2] -> 0, m[8, 3] -> 0, m[8, 4] -> 0, m[8, 5] -> 0, m[8, 6] -> 0,
>   m[8, 7] -> 0, m[8, 8] -> 0, m[8, 9] -> 0, m[8, 10] -> 1, 
>  m[9, 1] -> 0, m[9, 2] -> 0, m[9, 3] -> 0, m[9, 4] -> 0, m[9, 5] -> 0,
>   m[9, 6] -> 0, m[9, 7] -> 0, m[9, 8] -> 0, m[9, 9] -> 1, 
>  m[9, 10] -> 0, m[10, 1] -> 0, m[10, 2] -> 0, m[10, 3] -> 0, 
>  m[10, 4] -> 0, m[10, 5] -> 0, m[10, 6] -> 0, m[10, 7] -> 0, 
>  m[10, 8] -> 1, m[10, 9] -> 0, m[10, 10] -> 0, k -> 11}
> ```

Visualization:

```
dp = Dispatch[{1 -> {1, 1}, 2 -> {1, 4}, 3 -> {2, 1}, 4 -> {2, 2}, 
   5 -> {2, 3}, 6 -> {2, 4}, 7 -> {3, 1}, 8 -> {3, 4}, 9 -> {4, 1}, 
   10 -> {4, 4}}];
SparseArray[
  KeyValueMap[#2[[1]] -> #1 &]@GroupBy[
    Most[solution],
    #[[1, 1]] & -> (If[#[[2]] == 1, #[[1, 2]] /. dp, Nothing] &)
    ],
  {4, 4}, _] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 7 & \_ & \_ & 4 \\
 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 6 & \_ & \_ & 10 \\
 9 & \_ & \_ & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

We validate that $7+4=5+3+2+1=11=k$.

Comment: @ SneezeFor16Mim thanks for helping, but it seems to me that you misunderstood the problem as it also happened to me when I read it the first time, the image shows you the sums that should be the same,see issue of problem.

Comment: @BeTDa Oh yes... What was I thinking yesterday :^( But that's fairly easy as all you need to do is to modify `cons3`. I'll update the answer later.

Comment: @BeTDa Updated.

Comment: ,I have executed your code making the necessary modifications but I get this error  **LinearOptimization::vedom: The constraints include restrictions of some variables to the domain   Currently there is only support for the Reals.**
and I do not arrive at the result, and even less at the matrix representation .I'll put the execution somewhere

Comment: look here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zz4LOj6BP4UD9A2oEzE5iIbWXw7sf0zc/view?usp=sharing ,I use mathematica 12.0, I don't know if it influences something

Comment: update: I have noticed that in "domCons" changing integers for real works for me, but the result is rational, which does not fit the conditions of the problem.

Comment: @BeTDa Footer of documentation says `LinearOptimization` was "Introduced in 2019 (12.0) | **Updated in 2020 (12.1)**", and support for "Mixed-integer linear optimization" is one of the changes. You might want to upgrade to v12.1 to get integer result.

Comment: Too bad, I don't have the $$$ to migrate to version 12.1, is there any way to emulate your code in version 12

Comment: @BeTDa You can try the *Monte Carlo* method from @flinty 's answer, which is fast. If you want extremum sums, try `Minimize[{k, Flatten[{cons1, cons2, cons3, domCons}]}, vars, Integers]`. It's very slow, taking 3'47'' on my laptop, but still gives the correct answer, $20$.

Comment: ,Thank you very much for the time invested in helping me, I learned a lot about some things, one last thing, as I express with this new instruction the result in matrix form(Visualization) (like the one you drew in the generalization) , Maximize  for the other condition from what I see

Answer (score 2):

Sheer brute force is also an option if you need to generate lots of solutions and it's very fast. Here we randomly permute the range [1,10], saving permutations when the totals are equal:

```
results = DeleteDuplicates@Reap[Do[
      s = RandomSample[Range[10]];
      If[Total[s[[1 ;; 4]]] == Total[s[[5 ;; 8]]] == 
        s[[2]] + s[[6]] + Total[s[[9 ;; 10]]], Sow[s]]
      , 100000]][[-1, 1]];
```

In any given result, the first 4 elements are the column S1, the next four S2, and the last two elements are the middle two from S3. I'd say I got around 200 results on average each time I ran it. Here's a sample:

```
{{2, 7, 9, 3, 10, 1, 6, 4, 5, 8}, {10, 1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 9, 5, 7, 8}, {2,
   1, 10, 7, 8, 4, 3, 5, 9, 6}, {1, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 7, 4, 3, 10}, {9, 
  4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 3, 5, 6}, {4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 6, 5, 9, 3, 10}, {9, 4,
   3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1, 10}, {4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 1, 10}, {3, 7, 
  2, 10, 8, 4, 1, 9, 6, 5}, {2, 10, 3, 7, 4, 1, 8, 9, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 9,
   8, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 10}, {7, 1, 6, 8, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 2}}
```

---

I'd like to show it is possible to do it with `FindInstance` but it is very much slower than `LinearOptimization` used in **@SneezeFor16Min**'s answer:

```
s1vars = Array[s1, 4];
s2vars = Array[s2, 4];
s3vars = {s1[2], s3[1], s3[2], s2[2]};
allvars = Union[Join @@ {s1vars, s2vars, s3vars}];
constraints = (
   (*totals are the same*)
   Total[s1vars] == Total[s2vars] == Total[s3vars]
    (*all numbers unique*)
    && (And @@ (Unequal @@@ Subsets[allvars, {2}]))
    (*all numbers in 1 to 10*)
    && (And @@ (1 <= # <= 10 & /@ allvars)));
sol = FindInstance[constraints, allvars, Integers]

mtx = {{s1[1], x, x, s2[1]},
   {s1[2], s3[1], s3[2], s2[2]},
   {s1[3], x, x, s2[3]},
   {s1[4], x, x, s2[4]}};

MatrixForm[mtx /. First[sol]] /. x -> ""
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & & & 4 \\
 2 & 6 & 9 & 3 \\
 7 & & & 5 \\
 10 &  & & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You can try to get other solutions, for example: `FindInstance[constraints, allvars, Integers, 5]` but you will be waiting a very long time. However, note you can easily generate some new solutions with the same totals from any existing one by permuting the column elements not connected to S3 and the two middle elements on S3, as well as swapping the columns over.

Comment: ,Thanks for answering, I am studying your way of doing things, I am new to programming something, so I take a while to understand some things.