# 4X4 matrix of distinct cubed integers with identical row and column sums

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, parallelization, code-review, permutation

I wrote the following code:

```
ClearAll[findMat]
findMat = 
  Module[{csums = ConstantArray[#, 4], 
     mats = Select[DuplicateFreeQ[Join @@ #] &]@
       Subsets[Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@
         IntegerPartitions[#, {4}, Range[Ceiling[#^(1/3)]]^3], {4}]}, 
    Join @@ ((Select[Total[#] == csums &]@
          Tuples[{{#[[1]]}, Permutations[#[[2]]], 
            Permutations[#[[3]]], 
            Permutations[#[[4]]]}]) & /@ mats)] &;
solsB = ParallelTable[
   findMat2[n] /. {} -> Nothing, {n, 0, 10^5}];
{Total[#[[1, 1]]], MatrixForm /@ #} & /@ solsB
```

This code looks for a 4X4 matrix of distinct cubed integers with identical row and column sums. But Mathematica gave me an error about insufficient memory. How can I solve this problem? Or did I make mistake in my code?

Comment: Your code is very terse and compact. It may help explain what you're doing if you add some comments. What range of numbers can go in the matrix? If it's 1 to 16, then you need to test all of `ArrayReshape[#^3,{4,4}]&/@Permutations[Range[16]]` but that's 20922789888000 items, so you stand no chance of doing it this way. Your best course of action would be to use `FindInstance` as I described in a previous question of yours, but drop the diagonal constraints.

Comment: @flinty How do I drop the drop the diagonal constraints?

Comment: I commented the code there - you just need to delete two lines - the only other thing is you need to know the total in advance, but that could be removed if I introduce another constraint that all totals are equal https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226351/72682

Comment: @flinty So I need to delete the stuf under: * Both diagonals of the matrix *?

Comment: Yes, but more is needed I think as FindInstance will take a very long time to complete. Going back to your code above, you may want to look at `PowersRepresentations` instead of `IntegerPartitions`.

Comment: @flinty Can you help me modify my code?

Comment: The trouble is that there are very few small integers that can be written as a sum of four cubes in 8 ways which is a necessary but not sufficient requirement: `pwrs = ParallelTable[{n, PowersRepresentations[n, 4, 3]}, {n, 1, 4000}]; Select[pwrs, Length[Last[#]] >= 4 &]` -- edit: in fact there appear to be none all the way out to 18000 with `Length[Last[#]] >= 8 &]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only seven (six unique) solutions up to row/column sums of $10^8$ (of course there are 1152 equivalent squares by permutation/transposition for each one):
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 16 & 108 & 180 \\
 24 & 192 & 9 & 15 \\
 144 & 18 & 150 & 90 \\
 160 & 20 & 135 & 81 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 10 & 27 & 228 & 288 \\
 120 & 324 & 19 & 24 \\
 243 & 90 & 240 & 190 \\
 270 & 100 & 216 & 171 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 25 & 207 & 243 & 269 \\
 239 & 135 & 297 & 73 \\
 271 & 89 & 109 & 275 \\
 209 & 313 & 95 & 127 \\
\end{array}
\right),\\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 32 & 216 & 360 \\
 48 & 384 & 18 & 30 \\
 288 & 36 & 300 & 180 \\
 320 & 40 & 270 & 162 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 24 & 306 & 340 \\
 180 & 15 & 330 & 297 \\
 34 & 408 & 18 & 20 \\
 396 & 33 & 150 & 135 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 9 & 34 & 192 & 396 \\
 108 & 408 & 16 & 33 \\
 306 & 81 & 330 & 160 \\
 340 & 90 & 297 & 144 \\
\end{array}
\right),\\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 20 & 54 & 304 & 384 \\
 160 & 432 & 38 & 48 \\
 243 & 90 & 360 & 285 \\
 405 & 150 & 216 & 171 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The fourth solution is twice the first one.

I wrote a Mathematica code that searches up to a specific sum, but was not able to search beyond $300\,000$; only after translating the code to C I could find the above solutions (the smallest one having a row/column sum of $7\,095\,816$). Any Mathematica code will have to be very efficient to search beyond sums of 7 million, and I think Mathematica is not the right tool for this job.

For instance, the first solution has 65 decompositions into a sum of four cubes:

```
PowersRepresentations[7095816, 4, 3]

(*    {{1, 23, 76, 188}, {1, 62, 90, 183}, {2, 10, 118, 176}, {2, 16, 24, 192},
       {2, 16, 108, 180}, {2, 24, 144, 160}, {4, 34, 146, 158}, {4, 50, 110, 178},
       {6, 11, 70, 189}, {6, 11, 133, 168}, {6, 60, 138, 162}, {6, 64, 89, 183},
       {6, 66, 72, 186}, {6, 114, 138, 144}, {8, 30, 145, 159}, {8, 68, 82, 184},
       {9, 12, 87, 186}, {9, 15, 24, 192}, {9, 15, 108, 180}, {9, 108, 135, 150},
       {10, 23, 113, 178}, {12, 25, 48, 191}, {14, 36, 147, 157}, {14, 46, 77, 187},
       {15, 45, 63, 189}, {15, 66, 108, 177}, {15, 81, 90, 180}, {16, 18, 20, 192},
       {16, 101, 102, 171}, {18, 20, 144, 160}, {18, 72, 96, 180}, {18, 90, 144, 150},
       {20, 36, 97, 183}, {20, 81, 135, 160}, {24, 80, 114, 172}, {24, 90, 123, 165},
       {27, 44, 102, 181}, {27, 109, 134, 150}, {31, 86, 96, 177}, {33, 36, 96, 183},
       {34, 57, 135, 164}, {36, 52, 146, 156}, {36, 82, 144, 152}, {37, 58, 59, 188},
       {40, 50, 64, 188}, {42, 84, 121, 167}, {43, 48, 120, 173}, {44, 48, 99, 181},
       {49, 84, 120, 167}, {50, 67, 101, 178}, {50, 82, 110, 172}, {54, 60, 66, 186},
       {54, 86, 120, 166}, {54, 124, 135, 137}, {62, 66, 114, 172}, {62, 79, 97, 176},
       {64, 104, 130, 152}, {71, 102, 138, 145}, {72, 90, 139, 149}, {75, 96, 141, 144},
       {76, 81, 95, 174}, {81, 90, 135, 150}, {84, 91, 125, 156}, {86, 90, 123, 157},
       {94, 102, 108, 158}}    *)
```

#### C code

Ugly but fast code that finds all tuples $\{i_0,i_1,i_2,i_3\}$ whose cubes sum to a given value, and then tries all permutations to see if we can get a cube-magic square. The checks and permutations are hard-coded (using Mathematica to generate some code, at least).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define MAXSUMS 100
typedef struct {
  int number_of_sums;
  uint32_t sum[4*MAXSUMS];
} four_sums;

static inline void
check(const uint32_t a00, const uint32_t a01, const uint32_t a02, const uint32_t a03,
      const uint32_t a10, const uint32_t a11, const uint32_t a12, const uint32_t a13,
      const uint32_t a20, const uint32_t a21, const uint32_t a22, const uint32_t a23,
      const uint32_t a30, const uint32_t a31, const uint32_t a32, const uint32_t a33)
{
  uint32_t s0 = a00+a10+a20+a30;
  uint32_t s1 = a01+a11+a21+a31;
  uint32_t s2 = a02+a12+a22+a32;
  uint32_t s3 = a03+a13+a23+a33;
  if (s0 == s1 && s0 == s2 && s0 == s3) {
    printf("{{%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32"},"
           "{%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32"},"
           "{%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32"},"
           "{%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32",%"PRIu32"}}\n",
           a00,a01,a02,a03,a10,a11,a12,a13,a20,a21,a22,a23,a30,a31,a32,a33);
  }
}

static inline void
permute3(const uint32_t a00, const uint32_t a01, const uint32_t a02, const uint32_t a03,
         const uint32_t a10, const uint32_t a11, const uint32_t a12, const uint32_t a13,
         const uint32_t a20, const uint32_t a21, const uint32_t a22, const uint32_t a23,
         const uint32_t a30, const uint32_t a31, const uint32_t a32, const uint32_t a33)
{
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a33,a32);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a32,a31,a33);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a32,a33,a31);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a33,a31,a32);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a33,a32,a31);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a31,a30,a32,a33);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a31,a30,a33,a32);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a31,a32,a30,a33);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a31,a32,a33,a30);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a31,a33,a30,a32);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a31,a33,a32,a30);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a32,a30,a31,a33);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a32,a30,a33,a31);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a32,a31,a30,a33);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a32,a31,a33,a30);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a32,a33,a30,a31);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a32,a33,a31,a30);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a33,a30,a31,a32);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a33,a30,a32,a31);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a33,a31,a30,a32);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a33,a31,a32,a30);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a33,a32,a30,a31);
  check(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a33,a32,a31,a30);
}

static inline void
permute2(const uint32_t a00, const uint32_t a01, const uint32_t a02, const uint32_t a03,
         const uint32_t a10, const uint32_t a11, const uint32_t a12, const uint32_t a13,
         const uint32_t a20, const uint32_t a21, const uint32_t a22, const uint32_t a23,
         const uint32_t a30, const uint32_t a31, const uint32_t a32, const uint32_t a33)
{
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a23,a22, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a22,a21,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a22,a23,a21, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a23,a21,a22, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a23,a22,a21, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a21,a20,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a21,a20,a23,a22, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a21,a22,a20,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a21,a22,a23,a20, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a21,a23,a20,a22, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a21,a23,a22,a20, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a22,a20,a21,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a22,a20,a23,a21, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a22,a21,a20,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a22,a21,a23,a20, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a22,a23,a20,a21, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a22,a23,a21,a20, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a23,a20,a21,a22, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a23,a20,a22,a21, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a23,a21,a20,a22, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a23,a21,a22,a20, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a23,a22,a20,a21, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute3(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a23,a22,a21,a20, a30,a31,a32,a33);
}

static inline void
permute1(const uint32_t a00, const uint32_t a01, const uint32_t a02, const uint32_t a03,
         const uint32_t a10, const uint32_t a11, const uint32_t a12, const uint32_t a13,
         const uint32_t a20, const uint32_t a21, const uint32_t a22, const uint32_t a23,
         const uint32_t a30, const uint32_t a31, const uint32_t a32, const uint32_t a33)
{
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a13,a12, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a12,a11,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a12,a13,a11, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a13,a11,a12, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a13,a12,a11, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a11,a10,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a11,a10,a13,a12, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a11,a12,a10,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a11,a12,a13,a10, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a11,a13,a10,a12, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a11,a13,a12,a10, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a12,a10,a11,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a12,a10,a13,a11, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a12,a11,a10,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a12,a11,a13,a10, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a12,a13,a10,a11, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a12,a13,a11,a10, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a13,a10,a11,a12, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a13,a10,a12,a11, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a13,a11,a10,a12, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a13,a11,a12,a10, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a13,a12,a10,a11, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
  permute2(a00,a01,a02,a03, a13,a12,a11,a10, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
}

static void
check_sums(const uint32_t a00, const uint32_t a01, const uint32_t a02, const uint32_t a03,
           const uint32_t a10, const uint32_t a11, const uint32_t a12, const uint32_t a13,
           const uint32_t a20, const uint32_t a21, const uint32_t a22, const uint32_t a23,
           const uint32_t a30, const uint32_t a31, const uint32_t a32, const uint32_t a33)
{
  if (a00!=a10 && a00!=a11 && a00!=a12 && a00!=a13 && a00!=a20 && a00!=a21 &&
      a00!=a22 && a00!=a23 && a00!=a30 && a00!=a31 && a00!=a32 && a00!=a33 &&
      a01!=a10 && a01!=a11 && a01!=a12 && a01!=a13 && a01!=a20 && a01!=a21 &&
      a01!=a22 && a01!=a23 && a01!=a30 && a01!=a31 && a01!=a32 && a01!=a33 &&
      a02!=a10 && a02!=a11 && a02!=a12 && a02!=a13 && a02!=a20 && a02!=a21 &&
      a02!=a22 && a02!=a23 && a02!=a30 && a02!=a31 && a02!=a32 && a02!=a33 &&
      a03!=a10 && a03!=a11 && a03!=a12 && a03!=a13 && a03!=a20 && a03!=a21 &&
      a03!=a22 && a03!=a23 && a03!=a30 && a03!=a31 && a03!=a32 && a03!=a33 &&
      a10!=a20 && a10!=a21 && a10!=a22 && a10!=a23 && a10!=a30 && a10!=a31 &&
      a10!=a32 && a10!=a33 && a11!=a20 && a11!=a21 && a11!=a22 && a11!=a23 &&
      a11!=a30 && a11!=a31 && a11!=a32 && a11!=a33 && a12!=a20 && a12!=a21 &&
      a12!=a22 && a12!=a23 && a12!=a30 && a12!=a31 && a12!=a32 && a12!=a33 &&
      a13!=a20 && a13!=a21 && a13!=a22 && a13!=a23 && a13!=a30 && a13!=a31 &&
      a13!=a32 && a13!=a33 && a20!=a30 && a20!=a31 && a20!=a32 && a20!=a33 &&
      a21!=a30 && a21!=a31 && a21!=a32 && a21!=a33 && a22!=a30 && a22!=a31 &&
      a22!=a32 && a22!=a33 && a23!=a30 && a23!=a31 && a23!=a32 && a23!=a33)
    permute1(a00,a01,a02,a03, a10,a11,a12,a13, a20,a21,a22,a23, a30,a31,a32,a33);
}

int four_cubes(const uint32_t m)
{
  // compute the cube-root of the upper limit m
  uint32_t m3 = pow(m+1, 1./3);

  // compute the cubes of all numbers from 0 to m3
  uint32_t *cube = malloc((m3+1)*sizeof(uint32_t));
  if (cube == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: malloc failure\n", __func__);
    return 3;
  }
  for (uint32_t i=0; i<=m3; i++)
    cube[i] = i*i*i;
  
  // compute all possible decompositions of the numbers 0..m into four cubes
  four_sums *F = malloc((m+1)*sizeof(four_sums));
  if (F == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: malloc failure\n", __func__);
    return 3;
  }
  for (uint32_t i=0; i<=m; i++)
    F[i].number_of_sums = 0;
  for (uint32_t i0=0; i0<=m3; i0++)
    for (uint32_t i1=i0+1; i1<=m3; i1++)
      for (uint32_t i2=i1+1; i2<=m3; i2++)
        for (uint32_t i3=i2+1; i3<=m3; i3++) {
          uint32_t s = cube[i0]+cube[i1]+cube[i2]+cube[i3];
          if (s <= m) {
            if (F[s].number_of_sums == MAXSUMS) {
              fprintf(stderr, "exceeded MAXSUMS=%d at s=%"PRIu32"\n", MAXSUMS, s);
              return 4;
            }
            F[s].sum[4*F[s].number_of_sums+0] = cube[i0];
            F[s].sum[4*F[s].number_of_sums+1] = cube[i1];
            F[s].sum[4*F[s].number_of_sums+2] = cube[i2];
            F[s].sum[4*F[s].number_of_sums+3] = cube[i3];
            F[s].number_of_sums++;
          }
        }
  
  // check if any of the cube-decompositions gives a perfect square
  for (uint32_t i=0; i<=m; i++)
    if (F[i].number_of_sums >= 8)
      for (int i0=0; i0<F[i].number_of_sums; i0++)
        for (int i1=i0+1; i1<F[i].number_of_sums; i1++)
          for (int i2=i1+1; i2<F[i].number_of_sums; i2++)
            for (int i3=i2+1; i3<F[i].number_of_sums; i3++)
              check_sums(F[i].sum[4*i0+0], F[i].sum[4*i0+1], F[i].sum[4*i0+2], F[i].sum[4*i0+3],
                         F[i].sum[4*i1+0], F[i].sum[4*i1+1], F[i].sum[4*i1+2], F[i].sum[4*i1+3],
                         F[i].sum[4*i2+0], F[i].sum[4*i2+1], F[i].sum[4*i2+2], F[i].sum[4*i2+3],
                         F[i].sum[4*i3+0], F[i].sum[4*i3+1], F[i].sum[4*i3+2], F[i].sum[4*i3+3]);
  
  free(cube);
  free(F);
  return 0;
}

void show_usage(char const * const name)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <max>\n", name);
  fprintf(stderr, "Look for 4x4 squares of integers that have the same cube-sum"
          " in every row and column.\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "Scan numbers up to <max>.\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    show_usage(argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  long int m;
  if (sscanf(argv[1], "%ld", &m) != 1) {
    show_usage(argv[0]);
    return 2;
  }
  return four_cubes(m);
}
```

Compile with

```bash
gcc -Ofast -std=c99 -lm fourcubes.c -o fourcubes
```

and run with

```bash
./fourcubes 10000000
```

### Update

Here is a list of all 39 solutions with cubic row/column sums up to $10^9$. Maybe someone can find some order in these numbers.

```
{{{2,16,108,180},{24,192,9,15},{144,18,150,90},{160,20,135,81}},
 {{10,27,228,288},{120,324,19,24},{243,90,240,190},{270,100,216,171}},
 {{25,207,243,269},{239,135,297,73},{271,89,109,275},{209,313,95,127}},
 {{4,32,216,360},{48,384,18,30},{288,36,300,180},{320,40,270,162}},
 {{2,24,306,340},{180,15,330,297},{34,408,18,20},{396,33,150,135}},
 {{9,34,192,396},{108,408,16,33},{306,81,330,160},{340,90,297,144}},
 {{20,54,304,384},{160,432,38,48},{243,90,360,285},{405,150,216,171}},
 {{17,39,312,432},{204,468,26,36},{351,153,360,260},{390,170,324,234}},
 {{12,40,372,396},{144,480,31,33},{360,108,330,310},{400,120,297,279}},
 {{6,48,324,540},{72,576,27,45},{432,54,450,270},{480,60,405,243}},
 {{12,51,456,516},{144,612,38,43},{459,108,430,380},{510,120,387,342}},
 {{8,53,348,600},{96,636,29,50},{477,72,500,290},{530,80,450,261}},
 {{34,78,416,576},{272,624,52,72},{351,153,540,390},{585,255,324,234}},
 {{24,80,496,528},{192,640,62,66},{360,108,495,465},{600,180,297,279}},
 {{20,54,456,576},{240,648,38,48},{486,180,480,380},{540,200,432,342}},
 {{17,55,288,648},{204,660,24,54},{495,153,540,240},{550,170,486,216}},
 {{9,58,264,684},{108,696,22,57},{522,81,570,220},{580,90,513,198}},
 {{50,414,486,538},{478,270,594,146},{542,178,218,550},{418,626,190,254}},
 {{3,36,540,600},{264,22,590,531},{60,720,27,30},{708,59,220,198}},
 {{8,64,432,720},{96,768,36,60},{576,72,600,360},{640,80,540,324}},
 {{4,48,612,680},{360,30,660,594},{68,816,36,40},{792,66,300,270}},
 {{24,102,608,688},{192,816,76,86},{459,108,645,570},{765,180,387,342}},
 {{18,68,384,792},{216,816,32,66},{612,162,660,320},{680,180,594,288}},
 {{205,515,551,625},{543,385,681,287},{627,301,345,623},{521,695,319,361}},
 {{30,67,612,696},{360,804,51,58},{603,270,580,510},{670,300,522,459}},
 {{16,106,464,800},{128,848,58,100},{477,72,750,435},{795,120,450,261}},
 {{40,108,608,768},{320,864,76,96},{486,180,720,570},{810,300,432,342}},
 {{34,110,384,864},{272,880,48,108},{495,153,810,360},{825,255,486,216}},
 {{5,60,684,760},{76,912,45,50},{576,48,690,621},{828,69,480,432}},
 {{17,76,456,876},{204,912,38,73},{684,153,730,380},{760,170,657,342}},
 {{18,116,352,912},{144,928,44,114},{522,81,855,330},{870,135,513,198}},
 {{20,54,646,816},{340,918,38,48},{405,150,792,627},{891,330,360,285}},
 {{90,243,646,816},{432,160,792,627},{340,918,171,216},{891,330,384,304}},
 {{6,48,540,900},{120,960,27,45},{352,44,885,531},{944,118,330,198}},
 {{10,80,540,900},{120,960,45,75},{720,90,750,450},{800,100,675,405}},
 {{34,78,624,864},{408,936,52,72},{702,306,720,520},{780,340,648,468}},
 {{15,80,648,852},{180,960,54,71},{720,135,710,540},{800,150,639,486}},
 {{24,80,744,792},{288,960,62,66},{720,216,660,620},{800,240,594,558}},
 {{30,81,684,864},{360,972,57,72},{729,270,720,570},{810,300,648,513}}}
```

Comment: +1, you put a lot of effort into this. How long was it running for? You should also add -std=c99 and -lm to the compile options, because otherwise it will complain about libmath linkage.

Comment: @flinty thanks for the options, they weren't necessary on macOS so I didn't bother, but Linux may be different. The code took several hours to run on my 2.4 GHz Intel Core i9 (MacBook Pro).

Answer (score 5):

All credit to **@Roman** who deserves the accept for discovering 7095816 was the target number. With this number pinned down I tried to solve this myself with Mathematica, but it was still too slow:

```mathematica
variables = Array[x, 16];
matrix = ArrayReshape[variables, {4, 4}];
target = 7095816;

uniqueConstraint = (And @@ (Unequal @@@ Subsets[variables, {2}]));
rangeConstraint = (And @@ (1 <= # < 200 & /@ variables));
magicConstraint = And[
   And @@ (# == target & /@ Total[Transpose[matrix^3]]),
   And @@ (# == target & /@ Total[matrix^3])];

FindInstance[magicConstraint && uniqueConstraint && 
  rangeConstraint, variables, PositiveIntegers]
```

However, I was able to solve it in around two minutes using the [Z3 solver for Python](https://pypi.org/project/z3-solver). I figured since you have posted a handful of questions previously about these sorts of magic square problems, that you might find this useful should you wish to experiment further:

```python
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# the target sum
target = 7095816

# NxN matrix 
n = 4
vs = [ Int("x_%s" % i) for i in range(n*n) ]

# variables are 1 to 200
cnumber = [ And(1 <= v, v <= 200) for v in vs ]
s.add(cnumber)

# all distinct
cdistinct = Distinct(*vs)
s.add(cdistinct)

def cubesum(vlist):
    return sum(v*v*v for v in vlist)

# row totals equal column totals
for i in range(n):
    s.add(cubesum(vs[i*n:(i+1)*n]) == target)
    s.add(cubesum(vs[i::n]) == target)

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    r = [m.evaluate(v) for v in vs]
    print("sum: {}, vars: {}".format(target,r))
else:
    print("failed")
```

This produced the result:

```
sum: 7095816, vars: [144, 18, 150, 90, 160, 20, 135, 81, 2, 16, 108, 180, 24, 192, 9, 15]
```

... and if you look closely this solution is a permuation of **@Roman's** matrix.